# Каким способом можно нанести watemark на свой продукт?

Tags: javascript, slider

[Скрипт на облаке майла](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2xzw/jZsBU17AH).

Ссылка `Amazing Slider Free Version` в углу не прописана в HTML.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поспорил бы на счёт JS:

```
amazingslider.js:28:106
```

Comment: я это убирал уже - только title пропадает а сама ссылка остаётся

Comment: @Geyan, 1) Значит нужно было это описать в вопросе, раз Вы всё же нашли код ссылки. 2) Значит где-то ещё есть, такие вещи принято хитро привязывать, чтобы всякие там не убирали законную brandmark. Или же покупайте Branding Free.

Comment: вы исправили вопрос в этом вопросе было написано что мне сам слайдер до фени , а вот реализация этого мне нужна ,

Comment: @Geyan, кому какое дело до нужности Вам скрипта? Вопрос вроде о том, как ставят отметку, что далеко от "нужно - не нужно".

Comment: я о том и  говорю , сам слайдер мне не нужен , а вот как прилепили они ватемарк ...

Comment: @Geyan, человече, да какая разница? Или Вы боитесь что мы заподозрим Вас в том, что Вы хотите нашим трудом снять метку с бесплатной версии чтобы не покупать платную версию? Что ж, это и так все понимают. Ведь вопрос "Как?" очевиден - позиционирование ссылки.

Comment: я и сам догадался что позиционированием , да и платная версия и бесплатная мне до жопы , я сам могу слайдер написать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46843/discussion-between-other-and-geyan).